# Can't select items in PreferenceFragment on some devices

Tags: android, galaxy, preferencefragment

I have a few Android devcies I'm testing my application with. I have a `PreferenceActivity` that houses a `PreferenceFragment`. On a Samsung Galaxy S4, the preferences dispaly correctly and I can scroll through the list.

However, none of the preferences are selectable or editable. Nothing happens when I click them, and there are no errors in the log.

My activity extends from `Activity`, and my fragment extends from `PreferenceFragment`. The module depends on the Android Support v4 and v7 libraries.

Also, in my `PreferenceFragment`'s `onCreate()`, I call
`addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);`, yet the application didn't actually apply the defaults.

My min SDK is 18 for the app, and the device is running SDK 19.

I only have this problem on the Galaxy S4, and not other android devices I've tested with.